# Two home folder. Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning, mount

Hi to all,

Recently I installed Ubuntu 12.10. It's very nice and I like it very much. I have a few doubts about folders, as I was previously using Windows. In Windows, I have 3 local disks C,D,E. Now I did a partition in Ubuntu following these steps:

- partition with system data mounted is `/` 25 GB
- swap partition is 4GB
- partition dedicated to personal data mounted on `/home` that is 46 GB,
  because I only had an 80GB HDD.

My Doubt is if it is possible to create two home folders, like Windows' local disks D & E, to Store Data in different folders. Does anyone know how to create two folders to store data?

Comment: You want two home folders? But why? What do you have on disk D and what on disk E?


Is E a backup of D? Or do you store your files on D and somebody's else files on E?


Maybe there is an easier way to achieve what you want?

Comment: Well you can make a new folder with `mkdir`.

the current location of your `home` folder is `/`. So if you want another home folder just type in this:

`mkdir /Name_of_your_new_directory`

with `ls -la` you can check if you new folder is there...

Comment: Not a 2nd /home but you can create another directory and add that to home ;)

Answer (score 0):

If only the folders you use in ubuntu, I recommend ext4 partition with the partition that you can use at any time as an external drive.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not create two home folders.
There is no need at all to creat `/home` if you have other drives to keep your data.
We use mount flags to seperate certain files for the purposes of preventing loss of data like packages if an upgrade is due.
You might want to create a seperate mount point `/usr` as this is where all your apps and packages will go, and if you upgrade later on there's a very good chance you'll lose these if they're in the same block under `/`
If you're using a seperate mount point `/home` just to make sure you get enough space for your personal files, then there is no need to, `/home` is a folder in `/` if not created seperately, and thus has the same space.
However, if you have no place to keep your data when you upgrade then you will want `/home` flag to be defined. But most definitely creat a `/usr` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount a partition at any time. If you want it to appear under the folder /home, add it to /etc/fstab.

/dev/sdaX /home/myuser/myfolder auto defaults 0 0

/home is where your configuration files are saved. You don't want two homes.